# how to append iterrows in for loop

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, append

I am trying to create a sequence file/plate map. I want to assign certain positions coming from my map based (these are fixed segments of 9 numbers) based on a number in the "Cleaned GN" column. I need these positions in column.

For the number 1 it should have VialPos1 as shown in the code. I was hoping the same sequence would stack under it since there are more 1's. Then for the next number in the Clean CN column I am trying to tether map positions (2 goes with VialPos2).

```
 dfvp = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/xxx/AppDaxxx.txt',delimiter='\t')
 #ndf8['VialPos1']=''
 VialPos=[]
 for i, row in ndf8.iterrows():
     if row['Cleaned GN'] == '1':
        ndf8['VialPos'].append=dfvp['VialPos1']
     if row['Cleaned GN'] == '2':
          ndf8['VialPos'].append=dfvp['VialPos2']
         #print(ndf8)
        
ndf8.head(20)
```

It's not working. The output file only one set of vial positions.

Thank you!

Comment: If this is about pandas, please add the tag.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need `iterrows` you can use `apply`:

```
def compute_vialpos(row):
  if row['Cleaned GN'] == 1:
    return row['VialPos1']
  elif row['Cleaned GN'] == 2:
    return row['VialPos2']

df['VialPos'] = df.apply(compute_vialpos, axis=1)
```